# Trying to delete inaccurate entries from autofill in Thundbird Mozilla's email.

Tags: thunderbird, auto-form-fill

Using this site's recommendations, I'm trying to delete bad addresses from my Mozilla Thunderbird auto-fill-in feature. Called up Collected Addresses in a new email, as indicated. Highlighted ones to delete.  You're supposed to then type "DEL" according to this site's directions. WHERE DO YOU TYPE IT? Hitting the del key won't work. Where do you type the "DEL"?   I really need this.  Have been using Thunderbird for years and have so many bad addresses to delete. Seems most of my close friends now have three or four bad addresses and more often than not I send to the wrong edress! Help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to highlight the entry you wish to delete (either by hovering over it or using the arrow keys) and then press the Delete (or DEL) key to delete the entry.

Fun fact: This also works in Firefox for the search box, URL bar, and form auto fill drop downs!